# How to implement mTLS in the world of cloud computing

Tags: cloud, cdn, mutual-authentication, mtls

Morning all. I'm trying to understand the best practices for implementing mTLS in the world of cloud computing. The CDN services of the various cloud platform providers (AWS, GCP and Azure) don't seem to support mTLS. I can see that CloudFlare support it on their enterprise plan as does Akamai. Without the use of a CDN, the application puts itself at risk of DDOS attacks.

As far as I can see, the options are to use an expensive CDN like CloudFlare Enterprise in order to acquire DDOS protection, OR to not have DDOS protection and implement mTLS on privately managed reverse proxies without the use of a CDN. Neither are good.

Is there a best practice pattern for implementing mTLS in the cloud?